# Are there any functions which were proposed as elementary by mathematicians but not considered elementary now?

Tags: special-functions, math-history, elementary-functions

Are there any functions which were proposed by various mathematicians to be included in the set of elementary functions because of their properties but not considered elementary as of now?

Comment: The *notion* of [elementary functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) is less than $200$ years old.

Comment: @Lucian that's ok.